# Eclipse+Maven+JavaFX: maven javafx:run fails, but app works in terminal window

Tags: eclipse, maven, javafx

When I try to run Maven in Eclispe `clean javafx:run`, I get the message `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java"`.

Using the maven execution command debug output (removing brackets and colons) and execute it in a terminal window, the app starts as expected.

Where to search to fix Maven setup in Eclipse? or to search somewhere else?

IDE: Eclipse
Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043
Maven:   M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse    2.4.200.20231119-0901

Java version: 17
JavaFx version: 21

OS: Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon, Cinnamon version 5.8.4

POM: contains all dependencies

```
     ... 
     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>PVData/main.appUI.AppMain</mainClass>
    </configuration>
     </plugin>
    ...
```

Here is a part of the debug messages output

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [java, --module-path, /home/bxxxx/git/PVData/target/classes:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.10.1/gson-2.10.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/com/orsonpdf/orsonpdf/1.9.1/orsonpdf-1.9.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.9.1/univocity-parsers-2.9.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/jfree/jcommon/1.0.16/jcommon-1.0.16.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.2/controlsfx-11.1.2.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.5.4/jfreechart-1.5.4.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/jfree/jfreechart-fx/1.0.1/jfreechart-fx-1.0.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-core/12.3.1/ikonli-core-12.3.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-javafx/12.3.1/ikonli-javafx-12.3.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/21/javafx-base-21-linux.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/21/javafx-controls-21-linux.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/21/javafx-graphics-21-linux.jar, --add-modules, PVData, -classpath, /home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/jfree/fxgraphics2d/1.6/fxgraphics2d-1.6.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/kordamp/ikonli/ikonli-fontawesome-pack/12.3.1/ikonli-fontawesome-pack-12.3.1.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/21/javafx-base-21.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/21/javafx-controls-21.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/21/javafx-graphics-21.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/21/javafx-swing-21-linux.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-swing/21/javafx-swing-21.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.3.0/opentest4j-1.3.0.jar:/home/bxxxx/.m2/repository/org/testfx/testfx-junit/4.0.15-alpha/testfx-junit-4.0.15-alpha.jar, --module, PVData/main.appUI.AppMain]
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/bxxxx/git/PVData"): error=2, Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:594)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 36 more
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  2.055 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-04T21:18:22+01:00
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
```

Running the maven command in a terminal window. Was expecting to fail as reported inside Eclipse.

Comment: Perhaps [`JAVA_HOME` is not configured](http://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux) correctly.  See also, [install Java and JavaFX+Maven+Eclipse instructions](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java) at openjfx.io.

Comment: ...or the `PATH` environment variable. You can set environment variables in your Maven run configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) in the tab _Environment_ (to set it to the one of your system use a value like `${env_var:PATH}`). IMHO the javafx Maven plugin should not rely on any environment variable to be system independent.

Comment: note: prior to this question I was following the instructions to configure JAVA_HOME as well as following openjfx.io instructions.

As trial I installed now Maven on my Linux System. The first test shows positive result, being able to run the app.

At this point I suspect a setup issue within my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @b2405 Does it work when in your Maven launch configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) in the _Environment_ tab, you add the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with the value `${env_var:JAVA_HOME}`? Without that the Maven process started from within Eclipse will not see the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable specified in your system.

Comment: The Run Configuration has the `${env_var:JAVA_HOME` already.
I would need to further search to understand this situation.